# Outlook Error in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

The below code was working perfectly in last week and now am getting this error I don't know where it went wrong.

> unable to. cast com object of type 'system.__comobject' to interface type 'Microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem

```
Try
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Integer

    olApp = New Outlook.Application
    olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
    Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) 
    i = 1

    For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
        If InStr(olMail.Subject, TextBox1.Text) <> 0 Then
            olMail.Display()
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next olMail

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
End Try
```

Comment: Why you have commented everything in code??

Comment: please forget about that .. i was testing in some different ways.

Comment: I'm guessing you've updated Microsoft Outlook, or switched to a new computer or something. You will probably need to (re-)install the Office PIA for the version of Outlook you are using.

Comment: @ SSS thanks for that i will reinstall the office.. and try and comeback here.

Comment: Hi i have uninstalled the office and reinstalled it.. but am getting same error could you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is/are objects other than MailItem (e.g. ReportItem, MeetingItem) in the items list. Try below

```
Try
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oObject As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    olApp = New Outlook.Application
    olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
    Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail) 
    i = 1

    For Each oObject In Fldr.Items
        If TypeOf oObject Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            olMail = CType(oObject, Outlook.MailItem)  
            If InStr(olMail.Subject, TextBox1.Text) <> 0 Then
                olMail.Display()
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next olMail

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
End Try
```

Comment: Yes it did the trick.. really thankful for whatever you did..

tons of thanks.